How to navigate to the map application in Carplay when integrating Flutter application with Carplay?
In the application I made with Flutter, I integrated CarPlay with the flutter_carplay package. When an item is clicked on the POI screen in Carplay, it needs to open the map in Carplay and navigate to the location of that item.
Although it does navigate with the map application on the phone (with the map_launcher package), it does not do it with the map application in Carplay.
How can I open the map application in Carplay and navigate to that point when the item is clicked?

Have you got any solution for this?

@RagulPR Instead of using the flutter_carplay package, we integrated CarPlay with Swift ourselves.
